# execute script url from a reply to email using PHP

Tags: php, linux, email

I want to build a system where the user can just reply to the email he gets. What it needs to do is: once the user replies to the email, that email does not go to any user, it will execute a url with GET parameters that triggers a script that updates the database and send another user an email.

Let me explain again:
User A gets into the system to insert his message, his message will send a notification to User B, user B replies to it, but instead of sending to User A, it will Update a database and notify User A saying that User B has sent a message.

the main point is that User A and B does not communicate with each other directly, only allowing them to communicate using the system.

I need to use PHP.

If someone can help or point me into the right direction I will appreciate it!!

Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the system users, you could pipe within the .forward file to a php script.
Or run a php script via cron/wget that logs into that email account and processes emails.

Answer (score 0):

You need a email server, which will be receive and sent messages.
And just read new emails with PHP and do another magic that you want with [PHP IMAP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php).